# Words of a sentence appearing in separate nodes, Elementtree

Tags: python, xml, python-2.7, docx, elementtree

Basically I created a word document to check how the parsing in XML fares. I did :

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree  
import zipfile as zf  
z = zf.ZipFile("INTRODUCTION.docx")  
doc_xml = z.open("word/document.xml")  

tree = ET.parse(doc_xml)

NAMESPACE_PREFIXES = {
    'w': 'http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main'
    }  


text_elements = [element for element in tree.iter() if element.tag == 
'{' + NAMESPACE_PREFIXES['w'] + '}t']
for node in text_elements:
    print node.text
```

The Namespace prefixes is to take care of those links so that they are ignored. The node.text got printed as:

```
INTRODUCTION
This is a test document for xml
.
Lets
 see how this works.
Conclusion
It should hopefully
..
```

In my original document , `Lets see how this works` comes in a single line , similarly , I see the full stops of the same sentence appearing in separate nodes (like the "..") . How do I solve it? Here's the xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>\r\n
<w:document xmlns:wpc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingCanvas" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:r="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships" xmlns:m="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/math" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml" xmlns:wp14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingDrawing" xmlns:wp="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/drawingml/2006/wordprocessingDrawing" xmlns:w10="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word" xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main" xmlns:w14="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordml" xmlns:w15="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2012/wordml" xmlns:wpg="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingGroup" xmlns:wpi="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingInk" xmlns:wne="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2006/wordml" xmlns:wps="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2010/wordprocessingShape" mc:Ignorable="w14 w15 wp14">
    <w:body>
        <w:p w:rsidR="00470EEF" w:rsidRDefault="00456755"><w:pPr><w:rPr><w:b/></w:rPr></w:pPr><w:r w:rsidRPr="00456755"><w:rPr><w:b/></w:rPr><w:t>INTRODUCTION</w:t></w:r></w:p>
        <w:p w:rsidR="00456755" w:rsidRDefault="00456755"><w:r w:rsidRPr="00456755"><w:t>This is a test document for xml</w:t></w:r><w:r><w:t>.</w:t></w:r></w:p>
        <w:p w:rsidR="00456755" w:rsidRDefault="00456755"><w:proofErr w:type="spellStart"/><w:proofErr w:type="gramStart"/><w:r><w:t>Lets</w:t></w:r><w:proofErr w:type="spellEnd"/><w:proofErr w:type="gramEnd"/><w:r><w:t xml:space="preserve"> see how this works.</w:t></w:r></w:p>
        <w:p w:rsidR="00456755" w:rsidRDefault="00456755"/>
        <w:p w:rsidR="00456755" w:rsidRDefault="00456755"/>
        <w:p w:rsidR="00456755" w:rsidRDefault="00456755"><w:pPr><w:rPr><w:b/></w:rPr></w:pPr><w:r w:rsidRPr="00456755"><w:rPr><w:b/></w:rPr><w:t>Conclusion</w:t></w:r></w:p>
        <w:p w:rsidR="00456755" w:rsidRPr="00456755" w:rsidRDefault="00456755"><w:r w:rsidRPr="00456755"><w:t>It should hopefully</w:t></w:r><w:r><w:t>..</w:t></w:r><w:bookmarkStart w:id="0" w:name="_GoBack"/><w:bookmarkEnd w:id="0"/></w:p>
        <w:sectPr w:rsidR="00456755" w:rsidRPr="00456755"><w:pgSz w:w="11906" w:h="16838"/><w:pgMar w:top="1440" w:right="1440" w:bottom="1440" w:left="1440" w:header="708" w:footer="708" w:gutter="0"/><w:cols w:space="708"/><w:docGrid w:linePitch="360"/></w:sectPr>
    </w:body>
</w:document>
```

I noticed something like `w:type="spellStart"` and `"grasmStart"` which is the reason why `Lets` appears in a different node. Is there a way to look over this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`print` statement add newline after the string you print.

You need to group tags by `p` tags: Find `p` tags, and find `t` tags inside them.

```
...
w = 'http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main'    
for p in tree.findall('.//{' + w + '}p'):
    print ''.join(t.text for t in p.findall('.//{' + w + '}t'))
```

output:

```
INTRODUCTION
This is a test document for xml.
Lets see how this works.


Conclusion
It should hopefully..
```

Comment: thanks , could you explain what actually was happening and how this fixes it..?

Comment: @Swordy, I think I was editing the answer (adding explanation) while you were commenting. Please check out the answer again.

Comment: @Swordy, For the expression passed to the `findall`, see [`xml.etree.ElementTree` documentation - XPath Support](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xpath-support).

Comment: Can we add conditions w.r.t attributes of the text like color or font types?

Comment: @Swordy, If you follow the link I provided in the previous comment, you will find XPath syntax like `[@attrib='value']`. If you need more complex condition, you'd better look [`lxml`](http://lxml.de) which support more XPath syntax.

Comment: is it posiible for OOXML ? I tried xpath on ooxml and looks like i'm heading nowhere..

Comment: @Swordy I have no idea.

Comment: check my latest question, I guess microsoft office's xml is too complicated .. Check the answer there..

Comment: @Swordy, I added an answer there. Please check it out.